# how to keep the height of the div equal to the union of the height of elements inside it

Tags: css

I have been making a wordpress template. i got stuck at some place...

the problem is,

how to maintain the size of a div >= the size of p tags and img tags...

i have seen that the div only able to contain the p tag but the img tag over flows...

i have my code in this following order:

```
<div>
<p> some contents <img src="an_image"/> some morecontent</p>
<div>
```

what i basically want is:

```
div height = <p> height U(union) <img> height
```

but, what actually i am getting is:

```
div height = <p> height; while <img> over flows
```

i have already checked for similar questions on Stack Overflow but was not able to find one which solves a similar problem..
 please give me some idea..

an update:

this is my code:

```
<div id="the_content">
    <p><img class="alignright" src="http://i35.tinypic.com/990wtx.png" alt="WordPress Logo" align="right" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur quam augue, vehicula quis, tincidunt vel, varius vitae, nulla. Sed convallis orci. Duis libero orci, pretium a, <a href="#">convallis quis</a>, pellentesque a, dolor. Curabitur vitae nisi non dolor vestibulum consequat.  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=55#more-55" class="more-link">(more&#8230;)</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your CSS, but it sounds like you have a floated image inside the div. You may want to try a clearing div after the `<p>`. Or there are other, [newer solutions](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) detailed on Quirksmode.

Comment: ok! i will check this out! but floats are only possible with div! ryt! there is no other div inside that div,.. all elements are p and img.. and here in my case.. the img is overflowing from the div,. any solution for this?? where can i be possibly getting wrong..

Comment: @idlecool: Float is possible inside any block element, also img. But it *is* the div that is collapsing on you.

Comment: yeah! that was a overflow issue, i got the fix for it.. :)

i used 

div#the_content{overflow:hidden;}

and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify  the height it would wrap around all the elements inside it , why do you want to specify the height?

Comment: yeah! that is true when all elements inside it are directly child to that particular div..
 here in this case it the img element is inside p and p is inside the div,, its like div(p(img))... the same concept is not working here..

even have no control over the inner elements as it is rendering its content from CMS (wordpress)